# have 2 auto increment columns or match column data?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table called ptb_users it looks like this:

```
user_id   |   id (auto increment)  |  name   | email
0                    1               john     john@example.com
0                    2               kate     kate@example.com
0                    3               harry    harry@example.com
0                    4               lisa     lisa@example.com
```

basically i am running a query to insert data into the table like this:

```
$query="INSERT INTO ptb_users (user_id,
id,
first_name,
last_name,
email )
VALUES('NULL',
'NULL',
'".$firstname."',
'".$lastname."',
'".$email."'
)";
mysql_query($query) or die();
```

id is auto increment but i also want user_id to be auto increment, can this be done? or can i set a query that says copy the value that exists in id and set it in user_id as well?

i would really appreciate any help with this thanks.

Comment: it's because alot of my php code throughout the site cross references id and user_id

Comment: Your code smells. Given the data you are trying to store, is there a need for two auto-incrementing columns?